# How to create Sales Order directly from postman API?

Tags: api, dynamics-365

How to create sales order directly from postman web API (OData) to Dynamics 365 system?

Comment: On which exact platform you're trying to create Sales order? Is it Business central, Customer Engagement or FinOps in Dynamics 365? Show us the endpoint you tried

Comment: Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations.

Comment: Format is JSON.

Comment: Again, second google entry https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/create-retail-sales-order-using-rest-api-postman-mukesh-hirwani/?trk=read_related_article-card_title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create SalesOrder by doing a POST to .../OData/Company('mycompany')/SalesOrder

For more details on how to configure Postman you can refer to [Link](https://medium.com/capgemini-microsoft-team/dynamics-365-web-api-postman-collection-abfb259f9eae)